# MySQL Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

When I use this code below without the ?auth param, it works just fine.

```
                MySqlCommand createAccount = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO "+ Properties.Settings.Default.mysqlauth +".`account` (`username`, `sha_pass_hash`, `email`, `expansion`) VALUES (?username, ?pass, ?email, ?exp);", connector.connection);
                //createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?auth", Properties.Settings.Default.mysqlauth);
                createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", user);
                createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pass", hexHash);
                createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", email);
                createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?exp", expVer);
```

However when I add the database name parameter I get a fatal error.

```
                MySqlCommand createAccount = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO ?auth.`account` (`username`, `sha_pass_hash`, `email`, `expansion`) VALUES (?username, ?pass, ?email, ?exp);", connector.connection);
                createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?auth", Properties.Settings.Default.mysqlauth);
                createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", user);
                createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pass", hexHash);
                createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", email);
                createAccount.Parameters.AddWithValue("?exp", expVer);
```

I don't understand what's wrong here, shouldn't it work?

P.S. I've tried using the @ sign, doesn't change anything.

Comment: What is the "fatal error" that you are getting?

Comment: @JustinNiessner I get back "Fatal error encountered during command execution"

Answer (score 0):

The ? for bind variable is deprecated. You should use the @ sign. You cannot use bind parameters for table and column names. Bind parameters cannot change the structure of an SQL statement since the database will prepare the SQL statement and needs to know which table the statement refers to, to determine the query plan for execution.